# Why a container is overlapping the website cover image

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

Im building a frontend website with reactjs and bootstrap5, the problem im facing is that the container after the cover image is overlapping my cover image and i cant figure out why.

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import { Button, Cards } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import NavDropdown from 'react-bootstrap/NavDropdown';

function App() {
    return (
        
        <div className="App">
                
            <div class="container">
                <img class="bg-img img-fluid" src="./Crabscover.png"></img>
                <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark fixed-top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <img src="./logo.png" width="30" height="30"/>
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">CrazyCrabs</a>
                        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                        </button>
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">NFTdrop</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Connect</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </div>
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row">
                    <section class="text-light p-5 text-center text-sm-start " >
                        <div class="container">
                            <div class="d-sm-flex" >
                                <div >
                                    <p class="text-left">
                                        WELCOME TO THE WORLD OF PUDGY PENGUINS. A WEB3-BORN BRAND THAT 
                                        FOSTERS CREATIVITY, FREEDOM, AND COMMUNITY.THE PUDGY PENGUINS 
                                        BRAND PRODUCES CONTENT, MERCHANDISE, TOYS, AND DIGITAL COLLECTABLES.
                                        
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <img class="img-fluid" src="./cranking.png" />
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </section>
                </div>
            </div>
```

```
.App {
  text-align: center;
}

.App-logo {
  height: 40vmin;
  pointer-events: none;
}

@media (prefers-reduced-motion: no-preference) {
  .App-logo {
    animation: App-logo-spin infinite 20s linear;
  }
}



.App-link {
  color: #61dafb;
}

@keyframes App-logo-spin {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

.bg-img {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  object-fit: cover;
  filter: brightness(0.9);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}




.body {
  width: 100%;
}

.footer {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #277FD8;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

@media(min-width: 768px) {
  .news-input {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 16px;
}

/* Centered text */
.centered {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

/* Bottom right text */
.text-block {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 20px;
}
```

I already tried to delete or change the overlapping container for another section, but keep getting the same results, it overlaps my cover image.

Comment: Please be clear on what container you are referring to

Comment: Im referring to the container-fluid

Comment: solved it, just wrapped the navbar and bg image to a header content and the rest to body. Thanks